# How to load other window with delay in iphone

Tags: iphone, uiviewcontroller

I am loading my second screen with delay of 2 second. But I want to show my first screen as well for 2 second and after 2 second my second screen should be load. I have written code

```
[NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:2.0];
```

for delay. But my **MainWindow** is not appearing. I have written code inside of the function

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {    



....


}
```

Where to write the code to show first screen for 2 second.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use NSTimer for swap views like the following:
You can setup the Timer on:

```
  -(void) swapViews{
    // add the second screen as subview of the app window. 
    }

           (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
// add the first screen as subview of the app window. 
           [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:2.0
                target:self
                selector:@selector(swapViews:)
                userInfo:nil
                repeats:NO];
            }
```

Comment: I am getting error on swapViews. What is should declare for it ?

Answer (score 0):

Use this method too

```
[self performSelector:@selector(test) withObject:nil afterDelay:2];
```

Comment: What is test  word ? I added it inside of function but not appearing first screen .

Comment: I am getting an error [Myproject swapviews:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x9a342a0